# Get value From four table or more in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I want to get value from Four table and display it as follow in a GridView:

[image]

I manage to get the total of each table but the result under one column. how can i make each result in a column?

[image]

This is the Query i made to get the total from each table:

```
(
    select SUM(Amount_income_table) as 'Actual Income'
    from bacci.income_table
    where year(Date_income_table)='2017'
)
union
(
    select SUM(estimated_amount) as 'Estimated Income'
    from bacci.estimated_income_table
    where estimated_year='2017'
)
union
(
    select SUM(Amount_expenses_table) as 'Actual Expenses'
    from bacci.expenses_table
    where year(Date_expenses_table)='2017'
)
union
(
    select SUM(estimated_amount) as 'Estimated Expenses'
    from bacci.estimated_expenses_table
    where estimated_year='2017'
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would appear to want:

```
select 'Total Income' as which,
        (select sum(Amount_income_table) 
         from bacci.income_table
         where year(Date_income_table) = 2017
        ) as actual,
        (select sum(estimated_amount) 
         from bacci.estimated_income_table
         where estimated_year = 2017
        ) as estimated
union all
select 'Total Expense' as which,
        (select sum(Amount_expenses_table) 
         from bacci.expenses_table
         where year(Date_expenses_table) = 2017
        ) as actual,
        (select sum(estimated_amount) 
         from bacci.estimated_expenses_table
         where estimated_year = 2017
        ) as estimated
```

You can then get the totals, with an additional level of aggregation:

```
select which, sum(actual) as actual, sum(estimated) as estimated
from ((select 'Total Income' as which,
              (select sum(Amount_income_table) 
               from bacci.income_table
               where year(Date_income_table) = 2017
              ) as actual,
              (select sum(estimated_amount) 
               from bacci.estimated_income_table
               where estimated_year = 2017
              ) as estimated
      ) union all
      (select 'Total Expense' as which,
              (select sum(Amount_expenses_table) 
               from bacci.expenses_table
               where year(Date_expenses_table) = 2017
              ) as actual,
              (select sum(estimated_amount) 
               from bacci.estimated_expenses_table
               where estimated_year = 2017
              ) as estimated
      )
     ) ae
group by which with rollup
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to transform your query to give you what you want is:

```
SELECT 
    (
        select SUM(Amount_income_table)
        from bacci.income_table
        where year(Date_income_table)='2017'
    ) AS `Actual Income`,
    (
        select SUM(estimated_amount)
        from bacci.estimated_income_table
        where estimated_year='2017'
    ) AS `Estimated Income`,
    (
        select SUM(Amount_expenses_table)
        from bacci.expenses_table
        where year(Date_expenses_table)='2017'
    ) AS `Actual Expenses`,
    (
        select SUM(estimated_amount)
        from bacci.estimated_expenses_table
        where estimated_year='2017'
    ) AS `Estimated Expenses`;
```

Comment: @sako not my answer, I was 20s too late, wodin got it before me, so +1 on his ;) Don't forget to flag this answer as "solve my question" with the check just under the score number.